# How can I choose which parameter to pass to a multidecorated route in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am using the following code:

```
@api.route('/akilo/<a>/<b>/')
@api.route('/akilo/<c>/')
class Akilo(Resource):
    def get(self, a, b, c):
        if a and b:
            return a + b
        else:
            return c
```

to get different responses from the same resource, depending on which parameters I am using

When I make a request with:

```
/select/akilo/bom/dia/
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: get() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to change the signature of `get` to make `a`, `b`, and `c` optional.

```
def get(a=None, b=None, c=None):
```

Or you need to provide default values for the unused ones in your routes.

```
@api.route('/akilo/<a>/<b>/', defaults={'c': None})
@api.route('/akilo/<c>/', defaults={'a': None, 'b': None}) t
```

Comment: What if I have a "permanent" parameter like `/akilo/<a>/<b>/<x>/`and `/akilo/<c>/<x>/`?

Comment: It's still a good practice to give every variable in your route a default value in your view function. If you provide a value in the route, it will override the default value.